# Why does ie8 still recognize Twitter Bootstrap Large Size, after deleting col-lg out of CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm using Modernizer bundled with HTML 5 Boilerplate/Bootstrap, Respond.js, and for whatever reason i.e. 8 recognizes the large bootstrap column size even though I've removed it from the bootstrap.css.

Is there any reason that this would be happen?

In ie9-11 it's fine, and in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, all is well.

It just seems to be ie8.

Comment: did you clear your cache? IE is always trying to cache things for me I don't want it too.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache, then reload the page. Check again afterwards. :3

Comment: I'm using browserstack.com to check, when I stop and start another instance it doesn't fix.

Comment: @user1493230 Wow, that's really weird. I'm sorry, i don't see any reason why it would still show only in IE8. Is there any other thing's you should maybe delete from your CSS file? Like maybe an IE8 specific code, id, or class?